# How to get the value of method in java?

Tags: java, cryptography

I want the output from the code that `5=0101` if 1 occur double and add and if 0 occur only double from the algo

> Step 1: randomly select an integer s
>
> Step 2: compute the bit length Ls of s
>
> Step 3: compute L=n/Ls, Lr = n%Ls, Sr= s>> (Ls-Lr)
>
> Step 4: if (Lr=0) then compute M=sP Else compute M=sP and Mr=SrP
>
> Step 5: Q= Mr
>
> Step 6: for i=0 to L
>
> 6.1 Q=2LsQ
>
> 6.2 Q=Q+M
>
> Step 7: return Q

but this program doesn't return any output.
whats wrong with the code, please rectify the error.
Thanks in advance

```
package main;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class a {
    private static final double M = 0;
    static Object Q;
    
    public static double a() {
        //public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the no.:");
        int k = reader.nextInt();
        String str = java.lang.integer.toBinaryString(k);
        int n = str.length();
        Point P = new Point();
        Random r = new Random();
        int s = r.nextInt(50) + 1;
        int Ls = Integer.toBinaryString(s).length();
    
        int L = n/Ls;
        int Lr = n%Ls;
        int Sr = s>>(Ls-Lr);
        int Mr = 0;
        double Q = Mr;
        for (int i = 0; i<L; i++) {
            Q = (Math.pow(2, Ls)*Q);
            //int M;
            Q = Q + M;
        }
        return Q;
    }
    
    public void Q() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }       
}
```

Main method

```
package main;

import main.a;

public class newmeth {
    //private static final int Q = 0;
    //private static final String SrP = null;
    //private static final int M = 0;
    //public int Q() {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println("enter the no.:");
        a myjava = new a();
        myjava.Q();
        Object Q = null;
        a(Q);
    }
    
    public static int ya(Object Q) {
        //System.out.println("enter the no.:");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `a(Q);` - what are you try to do in this 'line of code' in your main method?

Comment: This looks like some obfuscated code that is very hard to read, any chances that you post original code so we can figure out what is wrong?

Comment: @ nadir L is the bit
length of the base point order n.
First, we should generate a random or specified integer s
with length of Ls bits. Then, we extend s periodically to a
positive integer k with Lk bits, Lk in the interval [1, L]. In the
extending process, if n is divided by Lk to q with positive
remainder r, we can pad the remainder section to keep the data adjoin repeating section. Next, we compute the value sP
denoted as M.

Answer (score 0):

If I will simplify your code and remove all unused variables - I will get something like that. and as you can see - you are not execute a() method from main()

```
package main;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString;

public class newmeth {
    private static final double M = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("enter the no.:");
    }

    private static double a() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the no.:");
        int k = reader.nextInt();
        int n = toBinaryString(k).length();
        int s = new Random().nextInt(50) + 1;
        int Ls = toBinaryString(s).length();

        int L = n / Ls;
        double Q = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++)
            Q = (Math.pow(2, Ls) * Q) + M;
        return Q;
    }
}
```

And minimal useful changes is change main method like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print(a());
}
```

And also please, check this out, and start calculate M based on your step 4 from your step by step guide

1. double Q = 0
2. into loop `Q = <...> * Q` what always return 0
3. `Q = Q + M` Q and M equal 0 so result still 0

Comment: it's not a solution, I just removed all unused code for best understanding, what increases chance to finding of mistake.

Comment: @divan seems like in your code you are lost `Step 4` from your guide, because M should be equal sP but in your code it's always equal 0.

Comment: int Lr = n%Ls;
        int Sr=s>>(Ls-Lr);
        double sP = 0;
  if(Lr==0)
        {
         M=sP;
        }
        else
        {M=sP;
         String Mr = SrP;
        }but it works nothing

Comment: `double sP = 0;` and then  `M=sP;` totaly SAME as `double M = 0;` Are you sure that `sP = 0` ? And also `int Mr = 0; double Q = Mr;` but you try to init Mr as `String Mr = SrP;` I am confused

Comment: actually sir, kP= summation(ranges from l = 0 to L-1) of 2^i *M where M= sP with s = sn,sn-1,....s1,s0 and P is the coordinates (x,y)